# JSON won't deserialise fully to C# class

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialise some JSON which looks like this:

```
{
   "Results":{
      "Prediction":{
         "type":"table",
         "value":{
            "ColumnNames":[
               "HT",
               "AT",
               "X",
               "Y",
               "Z"
            ],
            "ColumnTypes":[
               "String",
               "String",
               "Double",
               "Double",
               "Double"
            ],
            "Values":[
               [
                  "Mum",
                  "Dad",
                  "0.172627246490883",
                  "0.171741768332677",
                  "0.65563098517644"
               ],
               [
                  "Father",
                  "Mother",
                  "0.391368227731864",
                  "0.21270005247278",
                  "0.395931719795356"
               ]
            ]
         ]
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

The C# class looks like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Results Results { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public Prediction Prediction { get; set; }
}

public class Prediction
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Value value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    string[] ColumnNames { get; set; }
    string[] ColumnTypes { get; set; }
    string[][] Values { get; set; }
}
```

It deserialises up to the final property "value", which is not matched. If I turn on the error handling to see why I get the following error:

```
Additional information: Could not find member 'ColumnNames' on object of type 'Value'. Path 'Results.Prediction.value.ColumnNames', line 1, position 64.
```

I have a simple C# example which reproduces the whole problem:

```
var derek = @"{""Results"":{""Prediction"":{""type"":""table"",""value"":{""ColumnNames"":[""HT"",""AT"",""X"",""Y"",""Z""],""ColumnTypes"":[""String"",""String"",""Double"",""Double"",""Double""],""Values"":[[""Mum"",""Dad"",""0.172627246490883"",""0.171741768332677"",""0.65563098517644""],[""Father"",""Mother"",""0.391368227731864"",""0.21270005247278"",""0.395931719795356""]]]}}}}";

var returnedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <RootObject> (derek, settings);
```

I am pretty sure my class matches the JSON. Why doesn't it deserialise?

Comment: You forgot `public`...

Comment: See also [Json.net failing to load certain properties belonging to a class object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33704252/10263)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thanks,stupid embarrassing mistake inevitably!

Comment: @RobSedgwick oh it happens... and a second pair of eyes can help in those circumstances :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# properties default to private, they need to be public to be picked up by Newtonsoft/Json

```
public class Value
{
    public string[] ColumnNames { get; set; }
    public string[] ColumnTypes { get; set; }
    public string[][] Values { get; set; }
}
```